# How can I change the color of the webkit-progress-value in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input

I've spent hours looking at similar problems and nothing I try changes the fill color for the selected range in Chrome. Changing color in  `-webkit-progress-value` and `-webkit-progress-bar` does nothing. I've also tried some Vanilla JS as well, but that didn't work either.

I might have looked myself blind on this problem. What am I missing?

PS. I'm not able to get my code working here at Stack (sorry), but I have a [working example in Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Stieng/pen/OJPYYax)

```css
  
input[type="range"] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;    
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;       // Chrome reset
}
   
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {      
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #434b52;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #ff0000; // red
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #00ff00; // Green
}   

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {      
  -webkit-appearance: none;       // Chrome reset
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px #2bdeee;
  background-color: #25bbc8;
  cursor: pointer;      
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.kx-range {  
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

html {
  background-color: #262a2f;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kx-range">
  <input id="ranger" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="250" step="1">
</div>
```

Comment: `::-webkit-progress-value` only applies to the `<progress>` element. I don't believe (except in IE) that the two sections of the track are stylable the way you want. *"In IE, you are allowed to specify completely different styles for the upper (right of the thumb) and lower (left of the thumb) areas of the track."* - [CSs-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

Comment: Here another [**solution**](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/vEQGBe)

Comment: Thanks @DumitruChirutac. Exactly what I need - simple and neat. So many examples has too much js :)